# Submit a form obtained via XMLHttpRequest?

Tags: javascript, forms, dom

I am trying to a download a html page via javascript, parse it and submit the form with the following code. Everything seems to work perfectly in this function, yet I am unable to see the desired server side changes. Could someone point me if there's something wrong in this approach ?

```
function get_page(url){
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.responseType = "document"; //parse html
    xhr.open("GET", url);
    xhr.send(null);
    xhr.onload = function(){
        // get form here
        var dom = xhr.responseXML;
        var form = dom.forms[0];

        // set values in fields
        form[0].value='hello';
        form[1].value=form[0].value;

        //change action from # to url
        form.action = url;

        //EDIT: attach form to body
        document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(form);

        //form submit
        form.submit();

        //print form last value
        console.log(form[3].value);
    }
}
```

Comment: What does the network tab of your browser's developer console (press F12) display after executing above code?

Comment: The network tab is not showing any network call, which means that the form.submit() is failing. Now I dont know why ?

Comment: @bawejakunal it should show something for your first XMLHttpRequest

Comment: @bawejakunal You might need to open the network tab *before* reloading your site with above code.

Comment: Yeah the first xmlhttprequest got me the target page's html and I extracted the form too. Please check my edit. I tried attaching the extracted form to current page and then submitted it. This worked !

Comment: I think you should attach the `onload` event handler before sending the request.